# Pandas mean function that works with strings

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, apply, pandas-groupby

I need aggregation functions (mean, std, var, min, max, etc) that operate on a Pandas dataframe, can be called from groupby().apply() but **do not drop strings if all their values are the same**.

So:

`mean(['a','a'])` should yield `'a'`.

`mean(['a','b'])` should yield `NaN`.

Pandas behavior (as one would expect) is to drop non-numeric values:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':  [1,2,3],
                       'c2':  [1,1,1],
                       'c3':  ['a','b','c'],
                       'c4':  ['a','a','a'],
                       'cat': ['x','x','y']})
>>> df.mean()
c1    2.0
c2    1.0
```

Where I need:

```
c1    2.0
c2    1.0
c3    NaN
c4    'a'
cat   NaN
```

I also need these functions to an a per-group basis. So I created function that'll output strings as above, similarly to mean(), that I can then call from a groupby.apply():

```
def str_reduce(df):
    is_uniq = False
    try:
        is_uniq = df.unique().size == 1
    except:
        pass
    return df[0] if is_uniq else np.NaN
```

This works similar to mean when I apply it directly:

```
>>> df[['c3','c4']].apply(str_reduce)
c3    NaN
c4      a
```

However it now gives an unexpected result when I call it following a groupby?

```
>>> df.groupby(['cat']).apply(str_reduce) 
cat
x   NaN
y   NaN
```

What am I doing wrong? And/Or is there a better/easier way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.apply` on a groupby, it looks to apply a function to the entire grouped object. In this instance, you are looking to apply a function to each column within each group, so using `.agg` is much more appropriate and will give you the output you expect.

I think the function you wrote isn't entirely what you want, because you need to know which columns are numeric before-hand, otherwise it will not work properly for numeric columns. Instead, you can write functions that check if the dtype is numeric and proceed as normal, otherwise they apply your special rule.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

def mean_str(col):
    if is_numeric_dtype(col):
        return col.mean()
    else:
        return col.unique() if col.nunique() == 1 else np.NaN
```

So now you would do something like:

```
df.groupby('cat').agg(mean_str)
```

Output:

```
      c1  c2   c3 c4
cat                 
x    1.5   1  NaN  a
y    3.0   1    c  a
```

Comment: This worked for me except I needed to change `col.unique()` to `col.unique()[0]` so the result was not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help in any way?

```
list_columns=df.columns.tolist()
dict_new={}
for i in range(len(list_columns)):
    if(df[list_columns[i]].dtype)=='O':
        list_of_items=list(set(df[list_columns[i]].tolist()))
        if(len(list_of_items)>1):
            dict_new[list_columns[i]]='NaN'
        else:
            dict_new[list_columns[i]]=list_of_items[0]
    elif(df[list_columns[i]].dtype)=='int64':
        dict_new[list_columns[i]]=df[list_columns[i]].mean()

s = pd.Series(dict_new, name='ValueColumn')
test=pd.DataFrame(s)
test.reset_index(inplace=True)


index   ValueColumn
0   c1  2
1   c2  1
2   c3  NaN
3   c4  a
4   cat NaN
```

You can rename the column named index here to whatever you want.

Comment: A better way would be to not have the df[list_columns[i]].dtype)=='O' condition and just have df[list_columns[i]].dtype)=='int64' then perform mean else do the other condition. That way, even if it is not an object datatype , it will be handled